# Characteristic functions of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How can i prove with the $\epsilon$ definition of limit, that $X_n :\mathbb{N}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ where $X_n(x)=1$ if $x=n$ and  $X_n(x)=0$ if $x$$\neq$$n$ converges to zero?

What about $X_{\{n,n+1,,,,\}}(x)$ which converges to zero?

Thnak you in advance

Comment: what does mean $X_{\{n,n+1,,,,\}}(x)$ ? is the end of the question missing ?

Comment: you are right,i edited,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and take $N=n+1$. Then $X_n (x)= 0$ for all $n\geq N$ meaning that $|X_n(x)-0|=0<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. By definition this means that limit of $X_n$ is zero.